# Check if a drive can be removed

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

is there a way to find out if a drive can be ejected and removed (since it is a drive connected via USB) programatically?

If yes: how can this be done?

Comment: To the people voting to close this question, isn't it implicit that he's asking how to do this programmatically?

Comment: Do you wish to find out, whether a drive can technically be removed/ejected, or whether it is safe to do now?

Comment: This shouldn't have been flagged. The OP is just asking for a starting point.

Comment: This is a valid question. It only requires a small clarification on the side of OP.

Comment: @tenfour you can vote to reopen.

Comment: @Elmi If you want to eject the drive, what's stopping you from doing that? Why do you need to know ahead of time whether or not doing so will succeed? I think you should expand your question to make it a little more clear why you are asking.

Comment: My question is tagged with WinAPI, C and C++ - so it should be clear I'm asking for a solution to check this out of a program and don't want to eject anythign manually.

Comment: Do you want a solution in both C and C++? In my view there should be a single tag, namely `winapi`.

Comment: The duplicate doesn't answer this question exactly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Based on this MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> `GetDriveType` [..] determines whether a disk drive is a removable, fixed, CD-ROM, RAM disk, or network drive.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this only tells you if the drive is actually removable. It does not tell you if it is safe to actually remove the drive. Presuming that this is what OP wants to know, of course.

Comment: I downvoted, mine was the third one. This does not answer the question as asked.

Comment: @David: but it *does* -- this API tells whether a drive is removable: "... can be ejected and removed". Can you expand on what you are reading in the question?

Comment: I'm assuming that "can be ejected" means "is not busy working on locked files".

Comment: Admittedly that is a valid interpretation. In that case, the duplicate doesn't answer it either as it *will* eject, rather than check *if* it can. ("Garfield, you can be very destructive." "I can?")

Comment: That's what I think is the case too. However, I have to wonder if that's a time-of-check-vs-time-of-use (or in this case, -end-of-use) race condition...